# Is it possible to move mongodb indexes to another file system?

Tags: mongodb, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

Is it possible to separate MongoDB files location so the indexes are on another file system?

In the example below, I have database with 1.5TB of data + indexes of 330GB. 
I have a very fast storage that is not large enough to hold the entire data. 
I assume that if I move there the indexes I can get better performance.

Is there a way to do so?

```
# ls -l /data/mongodb --block-size=G
total 1962G
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 27 20:17 collection-0--8049282980716619517.wt
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 27 20:17 collection-2--8049282980716619517.wt
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 27 20:17 collection-4--8049282980716619517.wt
-rw-------. 1 root root 1627G May 27 20:17 collection-7--8049282980716619517.wt
drwx------. 2 root root    1G May 27 20:14 diagnostic.data
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 27 20:17 index-1--8049282980716619517.wt
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 27 20:17 index-3--8049282980716619517.wt
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 27 20:17 index-5--8049282980716619517.wt
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 27 20:17 index-6--8049282980716619517.wt
-rw-------. 1 root root   15G May 27 20:14 index-8--8049282980716619517.wt
-rw-------. 1 root root  320G May 27 20:17 index-9--8049282980716619517.wt
drwx------. 2 root root    1G May 27 13:54 journal
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 27 20:17 _mdb_catalog.wt
-rw-------. 1 root root    0G May 27 20:17 mongod.lock
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 27 20:17 sizeStorer.wt
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 23 12:50 storage.bson
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 23 12:50 WiredTiger
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 27 20:17 WiredTigerLAS.wt
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 23 12:50 WiredTiger.lock
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 27 20:17 WiredTiger.turtle
-rw-------. 1 root root    1G May 27 20:17 WiredTiger.wt
#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, this feature is only available when using the WiredTiger storage engine.

To use, invoke mongod like so:

```
mongod --dbpath /tmp --storageEngine wiredTiger --wiredTigerDirectoryForIndexes
```

In your dbpath, you will see a directory called indexes where indexes will be stored.

Also update yaml as

```
storage:
  engine: wiredTiger
wiredTiger:
  engineConfig:
  directoryForIndexes: true
```

Kindly note to try this in test environment once.
Please ask if any further help is required.

Source: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-965

Comment: Thanks. 
Do I need to rebuild the indexes or can I simply copy the index-* files the the new index directory?

Comment: Using the instructions by Priyanka Kariya I was able to create a new database with index directory. 
Is there any way to separate the index for an existing database ?

Comment: Should be possible to move the index file and use a symbolic link instead. Changing the logical location seems to be difficult.